# How to find Snowstone Island?

Tags: simpleplanes

I’ve been flying around the two islands available at the start of the game for ages, but I’m aware that on mobile there’s a third large island called Snowstone. But I just can’t seem to find it anywhere.

In the races section there’s a few I haven’t unlocked, including one called ‘yeti scramble’, which I can imagine is on this island.

So how do you find Snowstone Island?

Comment: @BunsGlazing I wasn’t sure if it would be the same on mobile, as a few of the islands aren’t there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the guide on the [/r/simpleplanes subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/SimplePlanes/comments/4ikbd4/guide_to_finding_the_discoverable_islands/), the way to find Snowstone island is as follows:

> Spawn at the Yeager Final Approach and [continue straight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfJFX.jpg).
>
> There will be very few islands on the way, however once you see [these 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVN6B.jpg) you'll know you're on the right path.
>
> [Another 2 islands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFLJS.jpg) will be ahead of you, and Snowstone's reflection will show up readily. Continue forward and you're home free.
>
> But be careful not to get hit by the [missiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8lD2.jpg)!

Another [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/SimplePlanes/comments/4ow1b4/i_made_a_map_of_the_simpleplanes_world/) also shows a map of the in-game world created by user /u/PerplexedPirate. This map contains all islands, not just the ones available on mobile, but according to commenters on the post the map is the same between PC and mobile other than the missing islands:
[image: Basic map of the simpleplanes world.]

Comment: Thank you, I’ve found it now! I’d already seen the first link, but I wasn’t able to find the island with that advice. The map was really useful though and let me find it without much difficulty!